# Access denied for upload image on host

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, plesk

I use the following code to copy image to path

```
public async Task<object> UploadImage(IFormFile file)
{
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\uploads\");
string fileName = file.FileName;

string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);

await file.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));
}
```

this code works fine in localhost, but when I publish my application on host get the following error:

```
Access to the path C:\Inetpub\vhosts\site.com\wwwroot\uploads\file.png' is denied.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to check and verify.

1. Make sure that at hosting env, you have created uploads directory under wwwroot.

- If not exists create it.

2. You have to give access to upload directory to apppool perimission ( App Pool under which your application is running).

Above things is required and your code is executed under apppool context.